# Nivo Slider Captions Transparent in IE7,8

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

For some reason, Nivo slider's captions aren't working properly in Internet Explorer 7 and 8. The text shows up (I can highlight it), but it appears to be entirely transparent.

URL: http://www.weblinxinc.com/beta/sssa/index.htm

Nothing I've tried has fixed it.

Comment: Do you use "css opacity"-tags AND a png with transparency? This will cause some problems in IE8 and older ... Maybe you should just try to use only a png or only the css opacity tag. Just a idea ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your nivo-slider.css file, you have `alpha(opacity=8)` for `.nivo-caption`, 
you want `alpha(opacity=80)`