# nivo slider not working in internet explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer, slider, nivo-slider

I am relatively new to web design. Nivo Slider works on Chrome, FF, Safari, but it does not work on Internet Explorer 8 and below.

I have been looking around google and stackoverflow for quite some time now, but cannot pinpoint the exact problem in my personal case.

Any help or direction to help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Here is the html, css, and javascript/jquery respectively:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/mainbanner.jpg" alt="main banner1" width="1000" height="500">
        <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/mainbanner2.jpg" alt="main banner2" width="1000" height="500">
        <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/mainbanner3.jpg" alt="main banner3" width="1000" height="500">
        <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/mainbanner4.jpg" alt="main banner4" width="1000" height="500">
        <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="images/mainbanner5.jpg" alt="main banner5" width="1000" height="500">
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.nivoSlider {
position:relative;
background:url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
.nivoSlider img {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
display:none;
}
.nivoSlider a {
border:0;
display:block;
}
```

nivo-slider.css

```
 /*
 * jQuery Nivo Slider v3.2
 * http://nivo.dev7studios.com
 *
 * Copyright 2012, Dev7studios
 * Free to use and abuse under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

/* The Nivo Slider styles */
.nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    max-width: none;
}
.nivo-main-image {
    display: block !important;
    position: relative !important; 
    width: 100% !important;
}

/* If an image is wrapped in a link */
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    z-index:6;
    display:none;
    background:white; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=0); 
    opacity:0;
}
/* The slices and boxes in the Slider */
.nivo-slice {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
}
.nivo-box {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.nivo-box img { display:block; }

/* Caption styles */
.nivo-caption {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    z-index:8;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=8);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
.nivo-caption p {
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
}
.nivo-caption a {
    display:inline !important;
}
.nivo-html-caption {
    display:none;
}
/* Direction nav styles (e.g. Next & Prev) */
.nivo-directionNav a {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    z-index:9;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nivo-prevNav {
    left:0px;
}
.nivo-nextNav {
    right:0px;
}
/* Control nav styles (e.g. 1,2,3...) */
.nivo-controlNav {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 15px 0;
}
.nivo-controlNav a {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.nivo-controlNav a.active {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

javascript/jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'fade', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
        slices: 15, // For slice animations
        boxCols: 8, // For box animations
        boxRows: 4, // For box animations
        animSpeed: 500, // Slide transition speed
        pauseTime: 2238, // How long each slide will show
        startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
        directionNav: true, // Next & Prev navigation
        controlNav: true, // 1,2,3... navigation
        controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
        pauseOnHover: true, // Stop animation while hovering
        manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
        prevText: 'Prev', // Prev directionNav text
        nextText: 'Next', // Next directionNav text
        randomStart: false, // Start on a random slide
        beforeChange: function(){}, // Triggers before a slide transition
        afterChange: function(){}, // Triggers after a slide transition
        slideshowEnd: function(){}, // Triggers after all slides have been shown
        lastSlide: function(){}, // Triggers when last slide is shown
        afterLoad: function(){} // Triggers when slider has loaded
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks for reading!

Sean

Answer (score 0):

In your nivo-slider.css file, you have alpha(opacity=8) for .nivo-caption, you want alpha(opacity=80)

Thanks to Wolff for this
[Nivo Slider Captions Transparent in IE7,8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178975/nivo-slider-captions-transparent-in-ie7-8)